Asian high school fight movie
I don't remember the title of and Asian movie where the protagonist has blonde dyed hair and the story revolves around rivalry between him and this other high school goer .. the fight takes place in heavy rain in the dark and they start wrecking this stadium with bright lights down in the course of their fight. They jump really high practically flying.
Any help with the title would be much appreciated.
